# How to use conditional in initialization list

Tags: c++

I have a child class that is derived from a parent class.  I need to use conditional logic to figure out which arguments to pass to the parent class constructor.  I am doing this as follows:

```
Child::Child(const std::string & foo)
        :Parent(foo=="x"?someClassPtr(new someClass()):someClassPtr(new someOtherClass()))
{
}
```

But what if I want to pass a different argument for foo=="y" and foo=="z"?  Is there some way to do this without using the ternary operator?

Comment: Perhaps a private static method to do the work and return the object. Perhaps smart pointers would be a good idea

Comment: I would consider adding a static factory method that contains the "if-else" statement. I would then consider templating on someclass/someotherclass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can definitely do it with nested conditional expressions, I would recommend against it: the expression borders on non-readable even with a single conditional, let alone two or three nested ones.

Using a private static member function would be a good choice for this task: the function could "parse" the value of `foo`, and decide on the proper object to return:

```
Child::Child(const std::string & foo)
:   Parent(constructParentArgs(foo)) {
}
private static someClassPtr *constructParentArgs(const std::string& foo) {
    if (foo == "x") return someClassPtr(new someClass());
    if (foo == "y") return someClassPtr(new someOtherClass());
    if (foo == "z") return someSubClassPtr(new yetAnotherClass());
    // provide a default value here
    return someClassPtr(new defaultClass());
}
```

The advantage of this approach for the readers of your code is that they do not have to bother themselves with the details of calling the parent constructor, unless they want to see what is going on. When they read the header, all they know that your code somehow creates parent argument. If they want to learn how exactly the argument gets constructed, they can always go straight to the private member function.